# Attach to a running C process with NetBean's debugger

Tags: c, debugging, netbeans

I have found links talking about how to connect NetBeans to a running Java process for debugging, but nothing on a C process.
Running on CentOS 7

Comment: What OS is the process you want to debug running on?

Comment: This might help you:  http://people.cedarville.edu/Employee/kshomper/cs4810_web/documents/tech%20talk/Attached%20Debugging%20Technical%20Paper.pdf